# Locu menu data on Foursquare API

Tags: api, menu, foursquare

I understand that menu data is available on Foursquare API via https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE_ID/menu

However, the Locu menu data set doesn't seem to be available.

For example, menu data is available for Da Mario:
https://foursquare.com/v/da-mario/4ac518daf964a520d8a820e3/menu

But this menu data is unavailable via the Foursquare API:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4ac518daf964a520d8a820e3/menu? [+ other parameters including oauth token]

Why is Locu menu data unavailable via the Foursquare API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Foursquare isn't allowed to redistribute Locu menu data through its API. Wish there were a better answer than this, but you can perhaps take a look at [Locu's own API](http://dev.locu.com/) for some ideas on how you can get access to the data you'd like.